# Map Drift on ArcGIS Pro Mobile Map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-android, arcgis-mobile, mobile-map-package

I am fairly new to ArcGIS Pro.  I have created an offline Mobile Map using ArcGIS Pro 2.3.0. which I am developing for a waypoint mapping project in Android.  The Mobile Map uses the Imagery basemap. The map localised to a small area in Caloundra, QLD, Australia.

The issue I have is when I enter a waypoint used Lat. Long. coordinates it appears on the Imagery map offset about 3 meters south-west.  I wish to shift the map north-east to align the view of where the waypoint marker (a Graphic on a GraphicsOverlay) should be (in relation to the imagery).

I have tried a few approaching including creating a map using 'GDA94 / Geoscience Australia Lambert (3112)' spatial reference.  However, I have yet to resolve this issue.

So my question is, how to I adjust (shift) a map?

Comment: What data format is the map in? If it's a raster, I would consider georeferencing the image or using the Shift tool: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/shift.htm